# Defining a new logical operator in Ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Very much an idle day-dream this but is it possible with some neat meta-programming trick to define a new logical operator in Ruby? I'd like to define a `but` operator.

For example, if I want to do something if `x` but not `y` is true I have to write something like:

```
if x and not y
```

But I would like to write

```
if x but not y
```

It should work exactly the same as `and` but would be down to the programmer to use sensibly to increase the legibility of code.

Comment: Not without a parser change. The semantics of the construct are unclear, IMO, without the `and`.

Comment: Can you give an example of why you think the semantics are unclear? It would work exactly the same as `and`. The only difference is that it would *imply* that the logical value of `x` was != the logical value of `y`.

Comment: What would `if x but y` mean? It's not a technical issue, it's a "Dave doesn't think it's clear" issue--purely preferential.

Comment: That would be an example of a BAD programmer abusing the construct. Maybe slightly better would be `unless x but y` - although it's still a bit rubbish. It basically fits well with the use case I describe in the question but not much else - which is why it's an idle daydream!

Comment: What I mean is, it's equally easy to abuse existing constructs: `unless not x and not !y` for example.

Comment: Like I said, purely preferential :)

Comment: Very interesting discussion overall. For most of my career, I only knew about if, and, not, and or. Then I started using Perl and became familiar with 'unless'. At first, I thought 'unless' was unnecessary. Over time, it started to make sense to me. So who knows? Maybe 'but' will emerge as part of the lexicon as well...

Comment: Your example `unless not x and not !y` is unwieldy but still makes logical sense. `x but y` just doesn't parse into any logical form

Comment: Fair enough, I'll concede that. I still don't think that diminishes it's (very slight) usefulness in the case of `x but not y`, and I still think if a code wrote `x but y` it would be them at fault for misusing the language rather than the language for providing that good old syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without editing the Ruby parser and sources and compiling a new version of Ruby, you can't. If you want, you can use this ugly syntax:

```
class Object
  def but(other)
    self and other
  end
end

x.but (not y)
```

Note that you can't remove the parentheses or the space in this snippet. It will also shadow the functionality of the code to someone else reading your code. Don't do it.

Comment: More importantly, this "solution" will always evaluate *both* `x` and `y` (no short circuit) and will do so in the *reverse order* (`y` then `x`).

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune And that's probably the reason overriding `&&` and `||` is not possible (while overriding `&` and `|` is).

Comment: @MladenJablanović: You just have to define a set of operators (let's call them *lazy operators*) which get translated to `a.OP { b }` instead of `a.OP(b)`, then it would be perfectly fine to do override them. A couple of years ago, I re-implemented all of Ruby's boolean operators as message sends, and I even used the `RubySpec` testsuite to verify their correct behavior: https://GitHub.Com/JoergWMittag/B001e/ BTW: Please focus on the *actual* semantics of that code ... this was the first ever Ruby project I wrote, and the code is *terrible* :-)

Comment: I agree. The best part in this answer is don't do it. +1

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to do this, try editing parse.y and recompiling Ruby. That's where Ruby's syntax is defined.

Comment: Why I would say its not recommended for anything with practical application, I think the user could learn something from trying it.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already pointed out, you cannot define your own operators in Ruby. The set of operators is predefined and fixed. All you can do is influence the *semantics* of some of the existing operators (namely the ones that get translated into message sends) by responding to the appropriate messages.

But of course, you can implement a `but` *method* quite easily:

```
class Object
  def but
    self && yield
  end
end

Object.new.but { not true }
```