# How to convert any method to infix operator in ruby

Tags: ruby, operators, metaprogramming

In some language such as Haskell, [it is possible](https://wiki.haskell.org/Infix_operator) to use any function taking two arguments as an infix operator.

I find this notation interesting and would like to achieve the same in ruby.

Given a imaginary method `or_if_familiar`
I'd like to be able to write something like `"omg" or_if_familiar "oh!"` instead of `or_if_familiar("omg", "oh!")`

How one would create such a notation in ruby (without modifying ruby itself)?

Comment: I can't find any ruby example but I admit not having tried to write any code on my side yet

Comment: Since this is a feature of the _parser_ it is not possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A bit late to the party but I've been toying around with it and you can use operator overloading to create Infix operators just like in [python](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/384122-infix-operators/) (but with a bit more work), the syntax becomes `a |op| b`, here's how:

First a quick and dirty copy-paste to play around with Infix:

```
class Infix def initialize*a,&b;raise'arguments size mismatch'if a.length<0||a.length>3;raise'both method and b passed'if a.length!=0&&b;raise'no arguments passed'if a.length==0&&!b;@m=a.length>0? a[0].class==Symbol ? method(a[0]):a[0]:b;if a.length==3;@c=a[1];@s=a[2]end end;def|o;if@c;o.class==Infix ? self:@m.(@s,o)else;raise'missing first operand'end end;def coerce o;[Infix.new(@m,true,o),self]end;def v o;Infix.new(@m,true,o)end end;[NilClass,FalseClass,TrueClass,Object,Array].each{|c|c.prepend Module.new{def|o;o.class==Infix ? o.v(self):super end}};def Infix*a,&b;Infix.new *a,&b end
#
```

Ok

Step 1: create the `Infix` class

```
class Infix
  def initialize *args, &block
    raise 'error: arguments size mismatch' if args.length < 0 or args.length > 3
    raise 'error: both method and block passed' if args.length != 0 and block
    raise 'error: no arguments passed' if args.length == 0 and not block
    @method = args.length > 0 ? args[0].class == Symbol ? method(args[0]) : args[0] : block
    if args.length == 3; @coerced = args[1]; @stored_operand = args[2] end
  end
  def | other
    if @coerced
      other.class == Infix ? self : @method.call(@stored_operand, other)
    else
      raise 'error: missing first operand'
    end
  end
  def coerce other
    [Infix.new(@method, true, other), self]
  end
  def convert other
    Infix.new(@method, true, other)
  end
end
```

Step 2: fix all the classes that don't have a `|` method and the three special cases (`true`, `false`, and `nil`) (note: you can add any class in here and it will probably work fine)

```
[ NilClass, FalseClass, TrueClass,
  Float, Symbol, String, Rational,
  Complex, Hash, Array, Range, Regexp
].each {|c| c.prepend Module.new {
  def | other
    other.class == Infix ? other.convert(self) : super
  end}}
```

Step 3: define your operators in one of 5 ways

```
# Lambda
pow = Infix.new -> (x, y) {x ** y}
# Block
mod = Infix.new {|x, y| x % y}
# Proc
avg = Infix.new Proc.new {|x, y| (x + y) / 2.0}
# Defining a method on the spot (the method stays)
pick = Infix.new def pick_method x, y
  [x, y][rand 2]
end
# Based on an existing method
def diff_method x, y
  (x - y).abs
end
diff = Infix.new :diff_method
```

Step 4: use them (spacing doesn't matter):

```
2 |pow| 3      # => 8
9|mod|4        # => 1
3| avg |6      # => 4.5
0 | pick | 1   # => 0 or 1 (randomly chosen)
```

You can even kinda sorta curry:
(This only works with the first operand)

```
diff_from_3 = 3 |diff

diff_from_3| 2    # => 1
diff_from_3| 4    # => 1
diff_from_3| -3   # => 6
```

As a bonus, this little method allows you to define Infixes (or any object really) without using `.new`:

```
def Infix *args, &block
  Infix.new *args, &block
end

pow = Infix -> (x, y) {x ** y} # and so on
```

All that's left to do is wrap it up in a module

Hope this helped

P.S. You can muck about with the operators to have something like `a <<op>> b`, `a -op- b`, `a >op> b` and `a <op<b` for directionality, `a **op** b` for precedence and any other combination you want but beware when using `true`, `false` and `nil` as the first operand with logical operators (`|`, `&&`, `not`, etc.) as they tend to return before the infix operator is called.

For example: `false |equivalent_of_or| 5  # => true` if you don't correct.

FINALLY, run this to check a bunch of cases of all the builtin classes as both the first and second operand:

```
# pp prints both inputs
pp = Infix -> (x, y) {"x: #{x}\ny: #{y}\n\n"}

[ true, false, nil, 0, 3, -5, 1.5, -3.7, :e, :'3%4s', 'to',
  /no/, /(?: [^A-g7-9]\s)(\w{2,3})*?/,
  Rational(3), Rational(-9.5), Complex(1), Complex(0.2, -4.6),
  {}, {e: 4, :u => 'h', 12 => [2, 3]},
  [], [5, 't', :o, 2.2, -Rational(3)], (1..2), (7...9)
].each {|i| puts i.class; puts i |pp| i}
```

Comment: This is both beautiful and horrifying.

Answer (score 3):

In Ruby, whether the operator is prefix or infix is fixed by the parser.  Operator precedence is also fixed.  There is no way, short of modifying the parser, of changing these things.

## But you can implement the built-in operators for your objects

Although you may not change the fix-ness or precedence of a built-in operator, you may implement operators for your objects by defining methods.  That is because Ruby translates operators into method calls.  For example, this expression:

```
a + b
```

is translated into:

```
a.+(b)
```

Therefore, you may implement the + operator for an arbitrary object by defining the + method:

```
def +(rhs)
  ...
end
```

The prefix operator `-` causes a call to method `@-`, so to implement prefix - you do this:

```
def @-
  ..
end
```

## You may also use methods

You may implement your own infix operators as plain methods.  This will require a slightly different syntax than what you want.  You want:

```
"omg" or_if_familiar "oh!"
```

Which you cannot have.  What you can have is:

```
"omg".or_if_familiar "oh!"
```

This works because, in Ruby, the parentheses on method arguments may often be omitted.  The above is equivalent to:

```
"omg".or_if_familiar("oh!")
```

In this example, we would implement this by monkey-patching the String class:

```
class String
  def or_ir_familiar(rhs)
    ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Ruby does not have infix method syntax, except for a fixed and predefined set of operators. And Ruby does not allow user code to change the language syntax. Ergo, what you want is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Wayne Conrad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/238886/wayne-conrad)'s answer, I can write the following code that would work for any method defined in ruby top-level:

```
class Object
  def method_missing(method, *args)
    return super if args.size != 1
    # only work if "method" method is defined in ruby top level
    self.send(method, self, *args)
  end
end
```

which allows to write

```
def much_greater_than(a,b)
  a >= b * 10
end

"A very long sentence that say nothing really but should be long enough".much_greater_than "blah"

# or

42.much_greater_than 2
```

Thanks Wayne!

Interesting reference on the same subject:

- [Defining a new logical operator in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8297645/defining-a-new-logical-operator-in-ruby?rq=1)