# If statement operator as a variable in ruby

Tags: ruby, variables, variable-assignment, operator-keyword

I am trying to do something like this in ruby:

```
x = 0
y = 1
z = "!="

if x #{z} y
  puts "True"
end
#True
#=> nil

x = 1
if x #{z} y
  puts "True"
end
#True
#=> nil
```

Using a operator as a variable is not evaluating the expression. Any way to do this.

Comment: `if x #{z} y` is the same as `if x` because `#` introduces an end-of-line comment in Ruby.

Comment: ok any way to evaluate z as operator.

Comment: Can you please remove the irb-prompts (the `1.9.3-p429 :091 etc) as it is of no use and only makes your code harder to read and does not allow users to work with it using only a copy/paste.

Comment: You can try to use [`Kernel#eval`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Kernel.html#method-i-eval).

Comment: @DheerajGupta I'm curious, what are you trying to do? Why do you have the operator as a string?

Comment: @Stefan: implementing simple calculator / formula evaluator? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Note you can only interpolate within a double-quoted string or regex.

Comment: It might be overkill but you could try creating an [infix operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43429202/7324619)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this one

```
x = 0
y = 1
z = "!="

x.public_send(z, y)
=> true
```

The trick here is know that `3 >= 5` is syntactic sugar for `3.>=(5)`

Comment: Nice, though it may be prudent to recommend `public_send` instead.

Comment: Also worth noting that `x.public_send(z, y)` alone returns `true ` so if only the boolean is required then the if-expression is not.

Comment: Sure, I just wanted recreate the user example

Answer (score 4):

To reiterate the answer above, I'd suggest using `send`.

However, it *is* possible to write the code in your original style - you just need to [`eval`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-eval) (i.e. execute) it:

```
x = 0
y = 1
z = "!="

if eval("x #{z} y")
  puts "True"
end
```

Generally speaking, the use of `eval` is strongly discouraged. It can lead to major security issues (e.g. if you're evaluating arbitrary user input!), and is quite a slow operation.

Comment: btw, no need to interpolate the x and y into the string. :)

Comment: heh... I did it that way originally, then doubted myself and "corrected" it. I'll revert that change :)