# Dynamic operator in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Is it possible in Ruby to change an operator dynamically?
Instead of having :

```
x + y
x - y
x * y
x / y
```

I want to have :

```
operator_a = +
operator_b = -
operator_c = *
operator_d = /
```

Example:

```
x = 2
y = 4
operator_a = +

puts x operator_a y
```

I tried the example above, but it doesn't work.

Comment: You can't define new operators, no.

Comment: It might help to provide some context. Why is your operator dynamic in the first place? Are you implementing a calculator and the operator is user input?

Comment: Infix Operations are defined and fixed by the parser itself. You can see this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40888810/how-to-convert-any-method-to-infix-operator-in-ruby) for some more details. Additionally in the parser [Here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/parse.y#L2583) and [Here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/parse.y#L2745)

Comment: Yes, it's for a kind of calculator that will generate the operator randomly. Thanks for the resources.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds a bit pompous: you can **send** object x a message (operator_a) with y as argument. This is simpler than it sounds:

```
x = 2
y = 5
operator_a = :+ #or "+"

puts x.send operator_a, y
```

Comment: Or even more obtuse `operator_a = x.method(:+)` then `operator_a.(y)` or `operator_a = Integer.method(:+)` and `operator_a.bind(x).(y)` or `operator_a.bind_call(x,y)`

Comment: alias :operator_a, :+

Answer (score 0):

> it's for a kind of calculator that will generate the operator randomly

In Ruby, operators are implemented as methods of the same name, e.g. [`Integer#+`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.1.3/Integer.html#method-i-2B). You can invoke a method dynamically via [`send`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.1.3/Object.html#method-i-send) or [`public_send`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.1.3/Object.html#method-i-public_send) by passing the method's name as a symbol or string, e.g.:

```
2.public_send('+', 4)
#=> 6
```

This is as succinct as it gets. However, when the method name is dynamic, its not clear anymore which methods will actually be invoked by that line.

Therefore (especially when working with user input) I prefer to add a little translation layer between the input and the action. So instead of passing the operator directly to `send` or `public_send`, I'd probably do something like this:

```
case operator
when '+' then x + y
when '-' then x - y
when '*' then x * y
when '/' then x / y
end
```

It also makes it easier to add handle situations where operators don't match, e.g. having `^` for exponentiation or adding operator variants:

```
case operator
when '/', '÷' then x / y
when '^' then x ** y
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have already stated, what you're looking to do isn't technically possible so you'll need to find a different approach.  Here's another potential approach utilizing a custom method with string input:

```
def my_method(string)

num_1, operator, num_2 = string.split

  if operator == "oper_a"
  num_1.to_i+num_2.to_i

  elsif operator == "oper_b"
  num_1.to_i-num_2.to_i

  elsif operator == "oper_c"
  num_1.to_i*num_2.to_i

  elsif operator == "oper_d"
  num_1.to_i/num_2.to_i

  else
  "invalid operator"
  end

end

my_method "6 oper_a 3"
#=>  9

my_method "6 oper_b 3"
#=>  3

my_method "6 oper_c 3"
#=>  18

my_method "6 oper_d 3"
#=>  2

my_method "6 oper_e 3"
#=>  invalid operator
```